# optimize the below code such that not to execute the query if take more time

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the below code which is a simple jdbc java program which fetch the results upon execution of the query and retrieve the results and further store them in a resultset

The Statement.execute() method allows us to execute any kind of query like select, update. It returns boolean. If the return value is true, then it executed select query, get the ResultSet object and read the resulted records. If it returns false, then it can be update query, call getUpdateCount() method to get total records updated

```
public static void main(String a[]){

        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.
                    getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port num>:<DB name>"
                        ,"user","password");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            //The query can be update query or can be select query
            String query = "select * from emp";
            boolean status = stmt.execute(query);
            if(status){
                //query is a select query.
                ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                while(rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                }
                rs.close();
            } else {
                //query can be update or any query apart from select query
                int count = stmt.getUpdateCount();
                System.out.println("Total records updated: "+count);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try{
                if(con != null) con.close();
            } catch (Exception ex){}
        }
    }
```

Now my query is to I have to optimize this program in such a way like

1)It should print the time taken by query to execute at runtime

2) need to add the condition in such a way ...if the query takes more than 1 min then it should stop at that time means some counter should be there which will keep track of the time that it should not be more than 1 min

Please advise how to achieve

Answer (score 3):

- Log `System.currentTimeMillis()` (which returns the current time in milliseconds) as the last thing before executing your query. Subtract as soon as the `execute()` returns.
- And, use `Statement.setQueryTimeout(int seconds)` to specify your timeout value as

  ```
  stmt.setQueryTimeout(60);

  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  boolean status = stmt.execute(query);
  System.out.println("Took " + (start - System.currentTimeMillis()) + " ms");
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot I ws looking for more optimized performance solution , any way Thanks in advance

Comment: @SonuLall Sorry, I didn't understand your comments clearly. Do you mean this doesn't fit your needs? If yes, can you please update your question with more details on what you're expecting. If not, and the answer meets your requirements please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Comment: I just curious to explore how spring could help us to achieve the same or quartz or is there some thing new in jdk1.6  that will help us to achieve the same

Comment: Spring or all other ORMs like Hibernate would do the same. They just abstract and provide a simpler API but under the hood they all use JDBC only i.e. instead of you they would be calling `setQueryTimeout()` on your behalf. (That's the reason why you still have to provide them with a JDBC driver jar in the classpath.) Going that route would also mean refactoring all of your current JDBC code because you would have to use Hibernate or Spring JDBC's API. And, Quartz cannot achieve the same because it's a Scheduling engine (where you can run tasks at certain intervals) not an ORM software.